# How to trigger pipeline with last created git tag (Terraform - AWS codecommit)

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, terraform, cicd, aws-codecommit

I want to trigger pipelines in AWS from the last git tag created (Gitlab), in my terraform module I am telling it to fire the pipeline from a specific tag and that is working, but is it possible to pass a dynamic value? The idea is to trigger the pipeline with the last created git tag.

```
{
    "source"      = ["aws.codecommit"]
    "detail-type" = ["CodeCommit Repository State Change"]
    "resources"   = [data.aws_codecommit_xxxxxxxxx]
    "detail" = {
      "event"         = ["referenceCreated", "referenceUpdated"]
      "referenceType" = ["tag"]
      "referenceName" = [var.repository_tag_version]
    }
  }
```

var.repository_tag_version should be the latest git tag, there is a way to do this in terraform: git describe --tags --abbrev=0 to get the latest one?

Comment: You want to assign the value dynamically to the `"referenceName"` instead of changing the variable value manually?

Comment: That's correct @MarkoE

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to fix it.

1: Create a bash script, inside the script you need to do logic to clone the repository and get the tag you want to get. i.e:
external_script.sh

```
while getopts a: flag
do
  case "${flag}" in
    a) git_repository=${OPTARG};;
  esac
done
# Check out the repository to a temporary directory
temp_folder="temp"
mkdir "$temp_folder"
git clone "${git_repository}" "$temp_folder"
cd "$temp_folder"
git fetch --tags
last_git_tag=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)
# Export last_git_tag value to txt file
cd ..
echo "$last_git_tag" > "latest-git-tag-value.txt"
```

In main.tf:

```
resource "null_resource" "get_last_git_tag_created" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "bash ./external_script.sh -a $repository_link"
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    environment = {
      repository_link = "your_repo_url"
    }
  }
}
```

Read the value of the last git tag:

```
data "local_file" "read_file_content" {
    filename = "./latest-git-tag-value.txt"
    depends_on = [null_resource.get_last_git_tag_created]
}
```

Now, the value is in data.local_file.read_file_content, So the event trigger should looks like this:

"referenceType" = ["tag"]

"referenceName" = [{ "prefix": data.local_file.read_file_content.content }]